How to fix Clouldflare 524 error with server sent event
I am using Cloudflare Hosting is a content delivery network that acts as a gateway between a user and a website server. I'm using server sent event in code , but I can't connect to the specific url in server, it alway return 524 error.
Can I config clouldflare to ignore check timeout for only this url?

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-524-a-timeout-occurred/42342  I guess their timeout is 100 seconds, which seems like a long time, so you should troubleshoot the server-side code to see what's causing it to take so long to respond.
